# Texure stretching while uv is correct

Tags: uv

When i scale the circle on the top of the cylinder this happened.

Loopcut can't completely fix the problem.
here is the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PF2jejPL9mubRUGfa1KL3TWpaa1Y3Kt4/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share the file?

Comment: Hello and welcome, eve if it looks close to the mesh, the uvs could have stretching, to check that use a UV grid/checkerboard , either the one in blender or download one from the web and use it as image

Comment: You just need to edit your UV mesh (scale it in one or two axis separately ) if you see your 3D, instead of perfect squares, the checkerboard looks like rectangles

Comment: try applying the scale with control a